# Как заменить значение ячейки pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Пробую через .replace() заменить значения столбца, но либо меняется весь столбец на одно значение, либо ничего не происходит. В пандах только начинаю разбираться. Тут в разные датафреймы записываю нужные столбцы из таблицы

Исходная таблица:

```html
records—record                                      
Save Time: 2022-10-29 08:03:39                                      
Username: vova                                      
Severity = Critical,Major,Minor,Warning. Alarm status = Acknowledged and uncleared,Unacknowledged and uncleared. Maintenance Status is in NORMAL. Last occurred = 1 hours.                                      
                                        
                    SeverityID  Name    Type    Source  Name1   Location Information    Occurrence Times    First Occurred (NT) Last Occurred (NT)
-                   Critical301 Ivan    OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  14  2022-10-19 16:29:20 2022-10-29 07:59:40
Correlative alarm   Major   21825   Egor    OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  7   2022-10-17 14:51:05 2022-10-29 07:58:35
Correlative alarm   Major   21801   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  8   2022-10-17 14:51:05 2022-10-29 07:58:35
Correlative alarm   Major   21801   Ivan    OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  8   2022-10-17 14:51:05 2022-10-29 07:58:35
Correlative alarm   Major   21801   Egor    OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  8   2022-10-17 14:51:05 2022-10-29 07:58:35
Correlative alarm   Major   21801   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  8   2022-10-17 14:51:05 2022-10-29 07:58:35
Correlative alarm   Major   21801   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  8   2022-10-17 14:51:05 2022-10-29 07:58:35
Correlative alarm   Major   21801   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  8   2022-10-17 14:51:05 2022-10-29 07:58:35
Correlative alarm   Major   22214   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  5   2022-10-17 14:50:39 2022-10-29 07:58:10
Correlative alarm   Minor   21541   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  7   2022-10-17 14:50:30 2022-10-29 07:58:00
Correlative alarm   Minor   21541   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  6   2022-10-19 14:34:25 2022-10-29 07:58:00
Correlative alarm   Minor   21541   Masha   OSS OSS UH1925  Uncleared , 150, 123, error port=6007, ror code=N/A, Error message=handshake timed out  14  2022-10-17 14:50:49 2022-10-29 07:56:55
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter


alm_data_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('someData.xlsx', index_col=False))
date_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:,9]
alm_data_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:,6]
alm_data_df = alm_data_df.str.split(',', expand=True)
vendor_df = pd.DataFrame(alm_data_df.iloc[:,5])
vendor_df = vendor_df.dropna()
vendor_df.columns = ['vendor']
vendor_df.replace({'vendor':{'MNC=39':'Nokia', 'MNC=08':'Huawei'}})

        
alm_data_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:,7:9]
#alm_data_df.to_excel('stolb.xlsx')
#date_df.to_excel('date.xlsx')
#vendor_df.to_excel('vendor.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([vendor_df,date_df,alm_data_df], axis=1)
df = df.dropna()
df.columns = ['vendor', 'date', 'enodebcode', 'enodebname']
#df.to_excel('date.xlsx')


#with ExcelWriter('1.xlsx', mode="a") as writer:
  #  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Лист 13", index=False)

print(df)
```

Вот результат на выходе

```
     vendor                 date          enodebcode           enodebname
5    MNC=39  2022-10-21 05:05:53   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
6    MNC=39  2022-10-20 16:42:53   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
7    MNC=39  2022-10-20 12:06:20   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
8    MNC=39  2022-10-20 11:45:07   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
9    MNC=39  2022-10-20 07:06:04   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
10   MNC=39  2022-10-19 11:24:16   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
11   MNC=39  2022-10-16 05:10:05   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
12   MNC=39  2022-09-02 19:25:50   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
13   MNC=39  2022-07-04 18:08:03   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
14   MNC=39  2022-07-03 09:04:36   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
15   MNC=39  2022-06-06 17:09:35   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
16   MNC=39  2021-06-29 19:09:03   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
17   MNC=39  2021-01-28 10:45:45   EnodeBCode          EnodeBName
```

А в итоге в первом столбце должен быть Nokia или Huawei

Comment: не совсем понятно. зачем вы вообще сначала выделяете столбец, делаете операцию с ним, а потом пытаетесь как-то странно склеить? выделите все нужные столбцы сразу, и в нужном замените вендора.

Comment: вообще, вы не указали в вопросе саму проблему - что нужно сделать и на каких условиях. ну и неплохо было бы пример исходных данных в воспроизводимом виде привести.

Comment: Нужно чтобы значения ячеек в колонке vendor менялись на Huawei и Nokia, в зависимости от MNC=11 или MNC=10. А так странно склеил, потому что делал разбивку столбца на таблицу с разделителем " , ".  По другому не знаю как сделать правильно.

Comment: приведите пример исходных данных. можно даже ссылку на файлообменник.

Comment: Таблицу добавил в вопрос

Comment: Вы уверены, что это _нужная_ таблица?

Comment: Да, вот ссылка на пример https://disk.yandex.ru/i/iv-F24qd4E_xeg

Comment: В этом файле нет ни `MNC=11` ни `MNC=10`. Это явно не тот файл

Comment: Я вытаскиваю эти значения из столбца Location information, там они MNC=39

Comment: Вообще удалённый ответ Алексей Р должен был помочь. Очень странно.

Comment: @CrazyElf по-моему, все дело в исходных данных. Они до сих пор загадочны.

Comment: @АлексейР Ну да. Там, например, могут быть русские буквы вместо некоторых латинских. Да что угодно может быть.

Comment: А может быть такое что .replace() не работает из-за того, что не правильно записан датафрейм? Или какой вариант решения может быть, исходя из таблицы по ссылке выше?

Comment: Второй лист не имеет значения, т.к. сделан руками. Изначально только первый лист. Мне по сути нужно вытащить из столбца Location information: MNC=39,  EnodeBCode=950111,EnodeBName=L950111. И соответственно заменить MNC=39 на вендора

Comment: Для начала приведите вопрос в порядок. Данные должны соответствовать коду. Если вы показываете код, где меняете `MNC=11`, то и данные показывайте с этой строкой. Ну или любую другую выберите, но чтобы данные соответствовали коду, а не так, что "Здесь играем, здесь не играем, здесь рыбу заворачивали". Что в данных - то и в коде. И наоборот. Тогда можно дальше куда-то двигаться.

Comment: Поправил, сейчас актуальные данные

Comment: inplace=True добавьте в vendor_df.replace

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было а) в наличии пробелов, б) в неприсвоении результата преобразования фрейма переменной.
`.str.strip()` решил вопрос с пробелами. Переменной присвоил.
Немного, без фанатизма, оптимизировал код.

```
alm_data_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(r'c:\test\someData.xlsx', index_col=False))
date_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:, 9]
alm_data_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:, 6].str.split(',', expand=True)
vendor_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:, 5].dropna().str.strip().replace({'MNC=39': 'Nokia', 'MNC=08': 'Huawei'}) # .str.strip()

alm_data_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:, 7:9]
df = pd.concat([vendor_df, date_df, alm_data_df], axis=1).dropna()
df.columns = ['vendor', 'date', 'enodebcode', 'enodebname']
print(df)
```

```
   vendor                 date          enodebcode           enodebname
5   Nokia  2022-10-21 05:05:53   EnodeBCode=950111   EnodeBName=L950111
6   Nokia  2022-10-20 16:42:53   EnodeBCode=950111   EnodeBName=L950111
7   Nokia  2022-10-20 12:06:20   EnodeBCode=950111   EnodeBName=L950111
8   Nokia  2022-10-20 11:45:07   EnodeBCode=950111   EnodeBName=L950111
9   Nokia  2022-10-20 07:06:04   EnodeBCode=950111   EnodeBName=L950111
10  Nokia  2022-10-19 11:24:16   EnodeBCode=950111   EnodeBName=L950111
11  Nokia  2022-10-16 05:10:05   EnodeBCode=950111   EnodeBName=L950111
...
```

Дополнительно. Убедиться, что в столбце были пробелы, можно, например, так:

```
print(alm_data_df.iloc[:, 5].dropna().str.replace(' ','<пробел>'))
```

```
5     <пробел>MNC=39
6     <пробел>MNC=39
7     <пробел>MNC=39
8     <пробел>MNC=39
9     <пробел>MNC=39
10    <пробел>MNC=39
11    <пробел>MNC=39
...
```

Comment: Увы, но не помогло, столбик остался неизменным

Comment: @КостяРусанов "причина засора" найдена :) решение обновлено

Comment: А, ну пробелы я тоже предполагал как вариант. Хорошо, что разобрались. В принципе, это наверное решается ещё через регулярку в `split` по типу `\s*,\s*`

Comment: @CrazyElf `.replace({'MNC=39': 'Nokia', 'MNC=08': 'Huawei'},regex=True)` тоже рабочий вариант

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь в поиске и решении проблемы!

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter


alm_data_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('someData.xlsx', index_col=False))
date_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:,9]
alm_data_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:,6]
alm_data_df = alm_data_df.str.split(',', expand=True)
vendor_df = pd.DataFrame(alm_data_df.iloc[:,5])
vendor_df = vendor_df.dropna()
vendor_df.columns = ['vendor']

#-----------------------------------------------

for i in range(len(vendor_df)):
    if vendor_df.loc[i, 'vendor'] == 'MNC=11':
        vendor_df.loc[i, 'vendor'] = 'Nokia'
    elif vendor_df.loc[i, 'vendor'] == 'MNC=10':
        vendor_df.loc[i, 'vendor'] = 'Huawei'

#------------------------------------------------

alm_data_df = alm_data_df.iloc[:,7:9]
#alm_data_df.to_excel('stolb.xlsx')
#date_df.to_excel('date.xlsx')
#vendor_df.to_excel('vendor.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([vendor_df,date_df,alm_data_df], axis=1)
df = df.dropna()
df.columns = ['vendor', 'date', 'enodebcode', 'enodebname']
#df.to_excel('date.xlsx')


#with ExcelWriter('1.xlsx', mode="a") as writer:
  #  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Лист 13", index=False)

print(df)
```

Есть ещё вариант если не хотите использовать цикл `for`

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------

vendor_df['vendor'][vendor_df['vendor']=='MNC=11'] = 'Nokia'
vendor_df['vendor'][vendor_df['vendor']=='MNC=10'] = 'Huawei'

#-----------------------------------------------------------
```